# How do I make my git repository HTTP accessible

Tags: linux, git, apache

I have recently been tasked with hosting a git server on Linux. I am very new to the Linux world so it was struggle just to get where I am today. I am at the point where I have created a bare repository and can view it using GitWeb (hosted on Apache).

Since I can browse to it with GitWeb I figured my configuration of the apache server and git were correct, but I still cant clone the repository on a remote machine. Depending on how I have apache configured, I either get a 403 Forbidden error or a 404 error when attempting to clone.

I am not sure if my git repository isn't configured correctly, my apache configuration is bad, or the folder security makes it inaccessible. It could be multiple things.

I have since removed GitWeb so that I could work with the simplest git and apache configurations possible. I am sure there are plenty of different reasons for my issues, so I am more asking for a few common misconfigurations that might be the culprit.

Here are some portions of my apache configuration. My repository is located at /opt/git

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName gitserver
DocumentRoot /opt/git
<Directory /opt/git>
    Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
 ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/opt/git">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

As I said, I was able to (with a different configuration) browse to my GitWeb page, so apache is definitely running and at some point the VirtualHost was configured correctly, but something is definitely wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it wasn't an issue with apache, it is an issue with git. I needed to run the command
         `git update-server-info`

I was confused because [This Documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Public-Access) made it seem like the command would run automatically, since I just copied the sample hooks. I guess you have to run the command whenever you create a new repository?